# Register form in PHP not working correctly

Tags: php

I am having some trouble with my register form. It is registering new users perfectly, although the validation is causing me issues. When a user with the same username tries to register the validation picks this up perfectly, but i still get the diagloue box poping up confirming the user has successfully registered. I check the database when this happens and the user doesnt reigster as the validation has been carried out. How do I stop this happening?

basically what i am wanting to achieve is for the message to stop saying 'successful' when a new user tries to enter a username which already exists, as the validation is picking this up 
Here is my code

```
                <?php


    if ($_POST["register"]=="yes") {


//Declares the variables that will be posted to the database    
$username = $_POST['username'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);



//Checks the database to see if username exists already
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
$nums = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Checks the database to see if email address exists already
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query2);
$nums2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    if ($nums >= 1)
    //informs user if username already exists
     echo "Username already exists, click <a href = 'register1.php'>HERE </a> to try again";
    else if ($nums2 >=1)

    //informs user if email already exists
    echo "Email Address already exists, click <a href = 'register1.php'>HERE </a> to try again";

    else
    {

$insert = 'INSERT INTO users(username, first_name, last_name, email, password,role_id, disable, activate) VALUES("'.$username.'","'.$first_name.'","'.$last_name.'","'.$email.'","'.$password.'", 2,0,0)';

mysqli_query($db_connection, $insert);
  mysqli_close($db_connection);
           ("Location: mainpage.php");



  }


{
  $i = 1;

if ($i > 0) {
    die;
}
else 

      "<script>alert (\"Registration Successful, your account has been sent for approval, and will be activated within 24 hours. \");</script>";
       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
     }




     }



?>



<!-- Registration form -->
<form name="register" id="register" method="post" action="register1.php">
<input type='hidden' name='register' value='yes'>
<table border = '0'>
<tr><td><strong> First Name:</strong></td><td><input type = "text" name = "first_name" size="30" value=""></td></tr> 
<tr><td><strong> Last Name:</strong></td><td><input type = "text" name = "last_name" size="30" value=""></td></tr> 
<tr><td><strong> Username:</strong></td><td> <input type = "text" name = "username" size="30" value=""> </td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Email: </strong></td><td><input type = "text" name = "email" size="30" value=""> </td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Password:</strong></td><td><input type = "password" name = "password" size="30" value=""> </td></tr>
<tr><td> <strong>Verify Password:</strong></td><td><input type = "password" name = "password2" size="30" value=""> </td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<input type ="button" value="Register" input class='button' onclick="verifyForm()"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: As a security standpoint you might want to add/combine your query for username/email and say username and/or email already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional statements DO print the desired result but not stopping the program from executing.

For example:

```
$i = 1;

if ($i > 0) {
    echo 'I want to stop the program, you have entered invalid $i';
}
Register();
```

However, you will print the message, but `Register()` will execute too. Because `if()` block does not necessarily means stop from execution.

You either have to use `die()`, `exit` or `return` in functions/methods

E.g.:

```
$i = 1;

if ($i > 0) {
    die('I want to stop the program, you have entered invalid $i');
}
Register();
```

Comment: yes basically what i am wanting to achieve is for the message to stop saying 'successful' when a new user tries to enter a username which already exsists, as the validation is picking this up

Comment: @user3531070 well, I guess you can do it, after my explanation :)

Comment: can you please provide a little more guidance as I am new to PHP

Comment: @user3531070 just use die instead of echo :) look at my examples. Or, put the message which is always appearing into the `else` clause

Comment: ok its working now, except it wont show 'successful' popping up anymore here is the code: {
  $i = 1;

if ($i > 0) {
    die;
}
else 
  
   "<script>alert (\"Registration Successful, your account has been sent for approval, and will be activated within 24 hours. \");</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
  }
 
 
 

  }

Comment: well, $i is 1, if $i is more than zero then DIE, else -> show. It works as intended, isn't it?

Comment: yes it works perfectly, thanks. The issue i am having now is that i cant get the 'registration successful' to pop up when a new user registers

Comment: Repost your full code (and please, format it before that), into the original question

Comment: It's horribly formatted :) However, you did not get the point of my examples. You do not need this `$i` stuff. It was just to show you how a `true` if statement will not block the program. Get rid of it, and change echoes to die's